# Odoo - Default value for a many2one field?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, many2one

In Odoo, I wanted to set default fields which are filled by users for a `many2one` field. I can set default values for `many2one` field basically with `default=` function, but it's filled by me not by the users in the server. Here's my example:

```
class ProjectReport(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.report'
    _rec_name = 'project_name'

    project_name = fields.Char(string='Project Name', tracking=True)
    project_duration = fields.Float(string='Project Duration', tracking=True)
```

and my second class:

```
class ApprovalRequestWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'approval.request.wizard'
    _description = 'Approval Request Wizard'


    
    responsible_name = fields.Char(string='Responsible',
                                    default=lambda self: self.env.user.name)

    project_name = fields.Many2one('project.report', string='Inherited Project Name', default=lambda self: self.project_name.id)

    project_duration = fields.Float(string='Project Duration (h)', related='project_name.project_duration', tracking=True)
```

In this way, when the user select project name from `many2one` field, project duration values gets by itself. But I want project name  gets by itself also.

When the user created any project, I would like to have button called "Approval" which triggers wizard class filled by automatically. How can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can pass the project id in the context when opening the wizard and prefixing the field name with `default_` (`default_project_name`)

Comment: `context="{'default_project_name': active_id}` I can only get Project's ID in my field now. How can I match my Project's name with the ID of the Project ?

Answer (score 0):

In XML File, instead of:

`context="{'default_project_name': active_id}`

I use:

`context="{'default_project_name': project_name}`

and it's worked.

```
P.S. project_report field has to be Char in this type
```